# React Navigation confusion

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I started learning React Native, I know how to create TabNavigator or DrawerNavigator but I need access to `props.navigation` on the landing page where I don't have TabNavigation, how I'am supposed to get it?

I tried this:

```
const App = createStackNavigator({
    LandingScreen: { screen: LandingScreen },
    Register: { screen: RegisterScreen },
    Login: { screen: LoginScreen}});
```

But still, `this.props` are empty objects.

And what is stackNavigator in plain language, does it just define navigation in order to be able to use navigation?

Answer (score 1):

In your LandingScreen you can able to get the this.props.navigation. You can show your TabNavigation as your initial route. You can even set Stack Navigation for each Tab. For React Navigation(v2) Documentation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html

Stack Navigation:
Provides a way for your app to transition between screens where each new screen is placed on top of a stack.

```
//Stack Navigator
const App = createStackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: Tabs }, //You can nest your TabNavigator here, Hence the LandingScreen inside your HomeStack will shown as your Initial screen
    Register: { screen: RegisterScreen },
    Login: { screen: LoginScreen}}); 

//Sample Tab Navigator
const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeStack,
    Settings: SettingsStack,
  },
  {
    /* Other configuration remains unchanged */
  }
);

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  LandingScreen: LandingScreen,
  Details: DetailsScreen,
});

const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator({
  Settings: SettingsScreen,
  Details: DetailsScreen,
});
```

You can get your navigation Prop by using below

```
//LandingScreen Component
export default LandingScreen extends Component{
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({  //you can able to destructure your navigation prop here
    headerTitle: 'Langing Page'
  })

  render(){
    return(
      //your logic here
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I solved it, but thank you for your effort, you helped me to understand other thing..